# What is the difference between == and ===?

Tags: actionscript-3

What is the difference between equality:

```
==
```

and strict equality?

```
===
```

Comment: Things that are equal with `===` are more equal than things found to be equal with `==`.

Comment: This question gets asked every week, and it's impossible to search for because the search ignores equals signs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript === vs == : Does it matter which "equal" operator I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

=== is like == except that the datatypes are NOT converted.  So the result is true if and only if expressions **and** their types are equal.

For example:

```
var string1:String = "5"; 
var num:Number = 5;
```

Then `string1 == num` is true, but `string1 === num` is false.

As a result, === is generally considered "stricter".  See:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000686.html

Answer (score 4):

It is more strict. It will check if not only the value but also the type matches. For example `1 == true` will return true while `1 === true` will return false, because they have different types.

Answer (score 2):

`==` tests for non-strict equality while `===` tests for strict equality. Strict equality means that the data type of the compared expressions must match.

Here are some examples from the [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary044.html):

```
s1 = new String("5");
s2 = new String("5");
s3 = new String("Hello");
n  = new Number(5);
b = new Boolean(true);

s1 == s2; // true
s1 == s3; // false
s1 == n; // true
s1 == b; // false

s1 === s2;  // true
s1 === s3; // false
s1 === n; // false
s1 === b; // false

s1 !== s2; // false
s1 !== s3; // true
s1 !== n; // true
s1 !== b; // true
```

Answer (score 2):

[ActionScript operators](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html)

[Equality](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#equality):

> `==` Tests two expressions for equality.

[Strict Equality](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#strict_equality):

> `===` Tests two expressions for equality, but does not perform automatic data conversion.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer given by the creators of actionscript itself
== tests two expressions for equality.
whereas, === tests two expressions for equality, but does not perform automatic data conversion.

Comment: How does your answer differ from zzzzBov's post?